# Константные локальные переменные

Tags: c++, const

На следующий код `clang-tidy` выдаёт

> constness of `str` prevents automatic move

```
#include <string>

std::string foo() {
    const auto str = std::string{"42"};

    return str;
}

int main() {
    const auto str = foo();
}
```

Правда ли, что в таком случае надо все локальные переменные объявлять неконстантными? Или только классы с move конструкторами? А как же правило использовать `const` как можно чаще?

Однако конструктор копирования и перемещения явно не вызываются:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() = default;

    A(const A&) {
        std::cout << "&\n";
    }

    A(A&&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "&&\n";
    }

    int x = 42;
};

auto foo() {
    const auto a = A{};

    return a;
}


int main() {
    const auto a = foo();

    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```

Похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089730.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109336/discussion-on-question-by-warpoe---).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, как мне, так и всем, понятно, что вашу функцию можно заменить на:

```
A foo() { return A{}; }
```

Но и в этом случаи функция ничего не делает, и вместо нее можно просто использовать объект `А`, то есть ваш код:

```
const auto a = foo();
std::cout << a.x << '\n';
```

можно не задумываясь заменить на:

```
const A a = A{};
std::cout << a.x << '\n';
```

Современные компиляторы не хуже нас соображают, они все это делают, но перед этим еще могут предупреждать вас о том, что в вашем коде есть лишние попытки сделать код хуже.

В добавок ко всему этому в стандарт С++17 введено :

> **Обязательное избавление от копирования** Изменён смысл понятия prvalue: теперь это всего лишь инициализация.

Это значит, что
В коде  `A a = A{};` хоть всё ещё требуется **и конструктор**, и **конструктор копирования**, гарантированно будет вызван только конструктор. А значит будет выполнено:

```
const A a{};
std::cout << a.x << '\n';
```

Вот такая оптимизация и происходит, поэтому ничего перемещать или копировать не нужно...

Comment: Понятно, что минимальный код из примера можно переделать. Но функция в реальном коде больше, естественно

Comment: Другой код тоже оптимизируется,  я же ответил на конкретный вопрос на конкретном примере. Кажется вас интересовало почему не вызывается конструктор копирования или перемещения. Что с того, что в  функцию можете запихнуть кучу кода?  Смысл не меняется

Comment: нет, вопросы другие: "Правда ли, что в таком случае надо все локальные переменные объявлять неконстантными? Или только классы с move конструкторами? А как же правило использовать const как можно чаще?"

Comment: А если скажут прыгать с обрыва, также будете думать, с 10 метрового или 20? И нет такого правила "использовать const" как много чаще. Есть рекомендация. Более того, она появилась очень давно, когда не было ещё move semantic. Но самый ужас постигнет тогда, когда узнаете, что для коротких строк (где то до 15 символов) конструктор копирования эффективнее, чем конструктор перемещения...

Comment: Похоже что для `A a = A{};` уже даже копирующий конструктор [не нужен](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/txAnf7). (Но для кода из вопроса это не работает, конечно.)

Comment: компилятор имеет законное право здесь нарушить as-if принцип и сделать оптимизацию. Поэтому, вопросы на собеседованиях "сколько здесь будет вызвано конструкторов" давно потеряли смысл. Можно только отвечать от 0 до 2

Answer (score 1):

> Правда ли, что в таком случае надо все локальные переменные объявлять неконстантными? Или только классы с move конструкторами?

Не все, а те, которые возвращаются из функции по значению (и для которых перемещение отличается от копирования, т.е. для какого-нибудь инта никакой разницы нет).

> А как же правило использовать `const` как можно чаще?

Не понял вопрос. Или миритесь с возможной потерей производительности, или поменяйте это "правило".